# How to get a TD value using JavaScript when TD does not contain any ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where TD has no id however I have unique TH value. Example table is,

```
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="25%">
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="first odd">
            <th class="label">SKU</th>
            <td class="data last">904532</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <th class="label">Width</th>
            <td class="data last">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <th class="label">Lead Time</th>
            <td class="data last">49</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="last odd">
            <th class="label">Depth</th>
            <td class="data last">63</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to read the value of Lead Time in a var. How can I read is using javascript i.e. var= ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) Selector to filter the content of `TH` and select next element to it using [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) like so:

```
var lt = $('th:contains("Lead Time")').next().text();
```

Comment: Many thanks Norlihazmey, I need to select Table name too as this table is in a web page. How can I do so.

Comment: Your welcome, table name? did't see those table with name attribute

Comment: You want to get id of table of respective TH?

Comment: I want to select IT where id="product-attribute-specs-table"

Comment: Here `$('#product-attribute-specs-table th:contains("Lead Time")')`, like this?

Comment: Yes like that, but you missed to select jquery library on the left side. See this https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/sodfusso/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it as simply as:

```
var e = $(".even").find("td").text();
alert(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all `<td>` elements and get the required one by `index`

```js
var cells = document.getElementById('product-attribute-specs-table').getElementsByTagName('td');

alert(cells[2].innerHTML );
```

```html
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <colgroup><col width="25%">
    <col>
    </colgroup><tbody>
        <tr class="first odd">
            <th class="label">SKU</th>
            <td class="data last">904532</td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
            <th class="label">Width</th>
            <td class="data last">20</td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="even">
            <th class="label">Lead Time</th>
            <td class="data last">49</td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="last odd">
            <th class="label">Depth</th>
            <td class="data last">63</td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child` selector like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var leadTime = $("table tbody tr:nth-child(3) td").html();
console.log(leadTime);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <colgroup><col width="25%">
    <col>
    </colgroup><tbody>
        <tr class="first odd">
            <th class="label">SKU</th>
            <td class="data last">904532</td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="odd">
            <th class="label">Width</th>
            <td class="data last">20</td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="even">
            <th class="label">Lead Time</th>
            <td class="data last">49</td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="last odd">
            <th class="label">Depth</th>
            <td class="data last">63</td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```